# Xamarin Android Microcharts with Fragments

Tags: c#, charts, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to add a chart to my Xamarin Android application (Visual Studio 2017)
I followed this repository [MicroCharts](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts.Samples), [Post](https://blog.xamarin.com/microcharts-elegant-cross-platform-charts-for-any-app/)

I'm using a Navigation Drawer in my application. So I'm using fragments to add my code. Above mentioned repository is for Xamarin.Forms Cross Platform. But I'm just using Xamarin.Android.

I have a Xamarin.Android repository [here](https://github.com/Chindara/XamarinAndroidNavigationDrawer). 
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to this : https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts

Here is a simple demo about how to use `BarChart` in your `Fragment` :

First, Add it to your `UI`, **MGradesView.axml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <microcharts.droid.ChartView
        android:id="@+id/chartView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Second, your chart will need a set of data entries :

```
var entries = new[]
{
    new Entry(200)
    {
        Label = "January",
        ValueLabel = "200",
        Color = SKColor.Parse("#266489")
    },
    new Entry(400)
    {
        Label = "February",
        ValueLabel = "400",
        Color = SKColor.Parse("#68B9C0")
    },
    new Entry(-100)
    {
        Label = "March",
        ValueLabel = "-100",
        Color = SKColor.Parse("#90D585")
    }
};
```

Third, instanciate a chart from those entries :

```
var chart = new BarChart() { Entries = entries };
```

Modify your `MGradeFragment.cs` like this :

```
public class MGradeFragment : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        SetHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View view = LayoutInflater.From(Activity).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MGradesView, null);

        var entries = new[]
        {
            new Entry(200)
            {
                Label = "January",
                ValueLabel = "200",
                Color = SKColor.Parse("#266489")
            },
            new Entry(400)
            {
                Label = "February",
                ValueLabel = "400",
                Color = SKColor.Parse("#68B9C0")
            },
            new Entry(-100)
            {
                Label = "March",
                ValueLabel = "-100",
                Color = SKColor.Parse("#90D585")
            }
        };
        var chart = new BarChart() { Entries = entries };

        var chartView = view.FindViewById<ChartView>(Resource.Id.chartView);
        chartView.Chart = chart;

        return view;
    }

    public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_MGradeToolbar, menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: @york-shen-msft Is it not working in LineChart? (all the other chart types are working) When I try to change it a LineChart it gives an exception "An unhandled exception occured." MY code change var chart = new LineChart() { Entries = entries };

Comment: @Chindara, It should be work, would you mind open a new question and post more complete message ?